# How to handle inf and nans in Great Table

Tags: python, pandas, great-tables

I've got a dataframe that I want to format which includes inf and nan.

The dict for it is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Foodbank': {0: 'study',
  1: 'generation',
  2: 'near',
  3: 'sell',
  4: 'former',
  5: 'line',
  6: 'ok',
  7: 'field',
  8: 'last',
  9: 'really',
  10: 'particularly',
  11: 'must',
  12: 'drive',
  13: 'herself',
  14: 'learn'},
 '%(LY)': {0: -20.93,
  1: -19.23,
  2: -26.09,
  3: 150.0,
  4: 90.24,
  5: -23.85,
  6: nan,
  7: inf,
  8: inf,
  9: inf,
  10: inf,
  11: -35.48,
  12: nan,
  13: nan,
  14: -1.3}})

from great_tables import GT
GT(df)
```

It looks like this:

[image]

What I want is to have a dash or n/a to highlight it rather than inf which won't mean anything to an audience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
df['%(LY)'] = df['%(LY)'].replace(np.inf, np.nan)
```

Output:

```
        Foodbank   %(LY)
0          study  -20.93
1     generation  -19.23
2           near  -26.09
3           sell  150.00
4         former   90.24
5           line  -23.85
6             ok     NaN
7          field     NaN
8           last     NaN
9         really     NaN
10  particularly     NaN
11          must  -35.48
12         drive     NaN
13       herself     NaN
14         learn   -1.30
```

[image]